# Android UI - Efficient to achieve rounded rectangle shape in center with button and text view

Tags: android, kotlin

[image: I need UI as shown in the image. What is best way to achieve this]

Looking for your help. I am using constrain layout. On top of blue rectangle, I have other elements too, but not sure how to achieve the layout that I have shown in the image.

I tried using card view and text view and button inside it. Please let me know if I miss any details or some information is required. Just looking for better approach.

Comment: I tried with card view and having text view and button in side it. Please let if I miss any details or some information is required. Just looking for better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried using card view and text view and button inside it

This is fine. And you will need another layout inside CardView because CardView can only hold one child. You can use ConstraintLayout,LinearLayout, RelativeLayout... to hold your TextView and Button.